# Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to search product from the database and then display in view. But it showing me an error that is this...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 679
```

Here is the code of Controller

```
function search_prd()
{
    $query = $this->input->post();
    $this->load->model('prd/addprd');
    $prd_search = $this->addprd->prd_search($query);
    $this->load->view('prd_search', ['prd_search' => $prd_search]);
}
```

And this code is MODEL

```
function prd_search($query)
{
    $q = $this->db->from('purchase')
        ->like('item_name', $query)
        ->get();

    return $q->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: Do you have the exact line where it's being thrown? Basically you're passing an array when a string is needed and need to explicitly convert it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI's `input->post()` is an array containing POST data. The second parameter of CI's active record `like()` expects a string.  If you mean to pass an individual field value, you will need to access that index:

```
<input name="search_value">

$query = $this->input->post('search_value'); //notate the field being used here
```

Then you can query where like:

```
$this->db->like('column', $query); //query is now a string
```

Alternatively, if you mean to pass  the entire array, you can use `where_in()`

```
$this->db->where_in('column', $query); //if you assign $query to $this->input->post();
```